# Is it possible to use assembly with arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, assembly

I want to learn assembly, but would like to learn by doing, is it possible to learn and make something useful with arduino hardware? I dont know where or how to start something like this.

Comment: yes it is very possible ... you can write same kind of code as the C++ compiler generates

Comment: Which Arduino? The assembly language/instruction set is dependent on the microcontroller family.
At least some of the C++ compilers used in Arduino toolchains allow you to include inline assembly code.

Comment: What do you want to reach in the end? Assembly is hardware-dependent, so if you know learn how to program an Arduino uno using assembly, that will help you only to a very small degree if you later want to program Intel CPUs in assembly.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the [ARV libC](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/assembler.html) project as a starting point to HOW to get assmbler code running. And the [AVR Instruction Set Manual](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual-DS40002198A.pdf) to get hold of the actual assembler mnemonics.

Maybe also my own [AVR Assembly Project](https://kwasi-ich.de/blog/2019/11/15/pwm_rider/) might be a helpful starting point with its code available on GitHub.